# Is there a browser-page-instance identifier in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to distinguish if somebody watches the page from one tab, or multiple. Is there any way to do this? Of course I could generate date+random number, but then if the user reloads, it would just set another identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store some kind of unique session identifier.  `sessionStorage` has the upside that it is specific to a tab, so you could check on reload to see if it exists, and not replace it if it does, but it would not be present on a second, new tab until you create it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could send 'heardbeat' messages via ajax to your server. Something like this:

```
var myTabId = Math.random();
setTimeout( function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'yourserverscript.php',
    data: { tabId: myTabId }
  });
}, 1000);
```

And in `yourserverscript.php` you check how much different `tabId` values are sent within some seconds.

Answer (score 1):

But if I will open a new tab in same browser or Different browser, SessionID" will give you unique id for the entire session irrespective of the browser/tab, SessionID" will give you separate session id for each request or different browser on same machine you will get different session id's.